# AJAX 4 is not working in VS 2010 professional

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-ajax

[image]

I'm using Visual studio 2010 professional.I installed AJAX 4 four months before and i used it in my previous project.Now i start a new web application project but AJAX controls are not working.I try to drag and drop the controls but it is not display in the design page (i already added "script manager").I added the "System.Web.Extensions" in References and install the new AJAX 4 (Realesed May,2012) using NuGET 3rd party tool.Still the controls are not working !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of problem i usually face.
Delete the TAB from tool box. Remove the Ajax dll . Add the Dll and TAB again(Register the control again). Even if this doesn't work, try with the older version's of AJAX.